# AC_CHECK_HEADERS: include multiple files

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf

I'm looking at the legacy C project which relies on GNU Autotools. The existing M4 script (incorrectly) checks for *FreeType* headers like this:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(freetype.h)
```

which is not the way *FreeType* should be included. The right way is:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

How do I require that *all* headers are included in the test program, not *either* of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for multiple headers depending on each other, you can use AC_COMPILE_IFELSE

Also if you google for "freetype m4" you will find several macros how to detect freetype.